# Remove SOAP Header namespace on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, soap

How can I get rid of the generatated namespaces in custom header elements as shown below on UserName and Password on a Windows Phone Client calling a SOAP Web Service?

```
SOAP Header... 
<Authenticator xmlns="http://www.namespacename.com/services/">  
  <UserName xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestApp.App">myUserName</UserName>  
  <Password xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestApp.App">myPassword</Password>  
</Authenticator>  
...
```

Answer (score 0):

All depends on how you're generating your SOAP requests to begin with.  Sample code always helps.